# SQLAlchemy returns a result double - even when only one is expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a flask - sqlalchemy database.
I'dont understand nor do I find a solution. If I write a query, it returns the row double...
The database Class has indeed two rows, but they are different.

```
data = db.session.query(Class).filter_by(Class.id==1).first()
print(data)

<Class>
<Class>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'data' variable is not defined somewhere earlier in the code, resulting in two rows.

The query, as you have written it, should actually result in a TypeError (wrong use of filter_by method).
It should be either:

```
data = db.session.query(Class).filter_by(id=1).first()
```

or

```
data = db.session.query(Class).filter(Class.id==1).first()
```

Comment: I have data in use as many locations. I changed them al to data'xx', where xx represent a number :-), quick fix. However, i still have two results. In the debugging I can see the query, if I paste this in my sqlbrowser, I get one result. I copy pasted this in another file, without any other coding. I ran it, and again two results...

Comment: Ok, like two seconds later, the 'eureka' moment :-) In my functions file, I have that same code at the bottom. So on importing the 'function' it ran the code inside that file... even without calling it :-) logic i guess